# How to fix "INFO:Detected dialect: OSS" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am kinda new to programming and I tried to execute the below code but chrome page is getting loaded but no execution happens and I am facing the below error.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38) on port 27651
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Apr 19, 2019 12:23:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

My config 
windows 10, chrome driver V72 and selenium-3.141.59

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }

        driver.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The logs you have posted are not errors. It is the log from the chrome driver.
  As it is stated in the log, `Detected dialect: OSS` log level is `INFO`. It doesn't prevent your test from running.
- The code you have posted should surely print in the console `Test Failed`.
- In your code, you have not gone to the URL you have saved in the `baseUrl` variable. Before you get the title of the page, you should get the page. Otherwise, it won't give you the desired pages title.
- Do the following and your code will load the page and will print `Test Passed!`

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
```